# Using xms argument but not xmx

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I started a java application (java 8 version) using as start argument twice `xms`, instead of using once `xms` and once `xmx`. I changed it immediately but I was researching, what it would have been the impact.

Will it set the `xms` per default? Will it have not maximum Heap memory, having an impact on the Garbage Collector, being run less frequent or even not being run?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you, but no magic is going to happen.

The JVM will choose a value for `-Xmx` for you, depending on the version of the JVM, the amount of memory your machine has, the machine type (client or server class) and the operating system.

See for example

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html#sthref5
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size